# Loading dynamic data for a route in EmberJS : (Error: Object has no method addArrayObserver)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am struggling with this piece of code really bad @ the moment. I have a dynamic segment that I specify in my route as :

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('set', {path:'/set/:set_id'}); 
});
```

And accordingly,

```
 App.SetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params){
            return this.get('store').find('gift',params.set_id); // each set has a bunch of gifts that belong to it and are identified by set_id which acts as the primary key .
            }
    });

 App.SetController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(); // array controller since I expect an array of gifts to be returned when visiting this route
```

When this is executed I get a glaring error that says:

**Object[Object Object] has no method addArrayObserver**

My data is being loaded through fixture which is something like this :

```
App.Set.FIXTURES = [
        {
                id: 1,
                name: 'EmberJS'
        },
        {
                id:2,
                name: 'Routing'
        },
     ... ]
```

App.Gift.FIXTURES = [
        {
                id : 1,
                gift_name: 'random name',
                set_id: 1
        },

```
    {
            id: 2,
            gift_name: 'name 2',
            set_id: 1
    },
   ..]
```

The Gift model is extended as :

```
App.Card = DS.Model.extend({
        gift_name: DS.attr('string'),   
        set_id : DS.belongsTo('App.Set')
});
```

The route is loaded by a #linkTo helper tag within handlebars and upon clicking a set linkTo , It renders as expected like :

/set/1 or /set/2

but it does not load any data. I want it to load specific gift data that belongs to the set but it keeps giving me an:

Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' error .

**Where am I going wrong or what am I missing here ?**

Answer (score 1):

This happen when you have a controller that subclass the `Ember.ArrayController` in your case  `App.SetController`, but the data set in the content property from the controller is an object instead of an array.

I think that `this.get('store').find('gift',params.set_id);` is causing this problem. Because `find` return the first object that mathes the value of `params.set_id`.

`Ember.ArrayController` expect an array in your content property, and `Ember.ObjectController` an object. In your case I recommend to use the `Ember.ObjectController`, because you are handling one object.

I hope it helps

Comment: Hey. App.setController extends Ember.ArrayController.There does not seem to be a findByProperty name but I think the problem possibly lies with the find method as you pointed out. However, if you look @ 
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-a-record/ , this shows that my approach is correct. It definitely is not returning an array, why that is happening, I am not quite sure :(

Comment: Sorry I made a miskate. findByProperty is a method of array class injected by ember. The code `this.get('store').find ...` is correct, because find is a method of Store. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set is a singleton, with a one-to-many relation to gifts.

Your SetController must be of type ObjectController, your data something like:

```
App.Set.FIXTURES = {
id: 1,
name: 'some name',
gifts: [{
id: 1,
name: 'some name'
},{
id: 2,
name: 'some name'
}]
};
```